# What is the best coding pattern in asp.net for calling a web service which requires polling?

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, webrequest, polling

In ASP.NET, I have to call a reporting service which has the following semantics:
1. create a report
2. check if report is ready for download
3. download the report

My current implementation is that #2 is done in a loop with a Thread.Sleep(1000) so that I poll every second.

I am wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this using ASP.NET 4.5 Async Methods.

Comment: does it take pretty long for the report to be generated (long enough to cause a request timeout on the client side)?  If not, I would think with an async method, just waiting for the report would be ok since the request wouldn't block.

Comment: I can't just "wait" - I have to poll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to poll using async then use `Task.Delay` instead of Thread.Sleep:

```
while (await proxy.PollServer())
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}

return await proxy.DownloadReport();
```

You could, as mentioned, flip your architecture so the server will notify the clients upon completion using `SignalR`:

Comment: I have no control over the server or the client. Mine is a web service proxy tier.

Comment: Difference of Tread.Sleep and Task.Delay is what is done to the calling thread. With Thread.Sleep the thread is blocked.  But if, as in my case, there is no other work to be done in the while loop, then is there any difference between Tread.Sleep and Task.Delay?

Comment: @ChrisHarrington it was added in .Net 4.5 as part of the whole async-await thing. it creates a Timer internally so it doesn't use up a thread.

Comment: @ChrisHarrington the behavior is similar because both have the same motivation of halting execution for a limited timespan. But Task.Delay frees up the thread to work on other parts of your system while Thread.Sleep wastes resources and hurts scalability.

Answer (score 3):

I would read about:

[WCF Duplex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/introduction-to-signalr)

And check what suits you the most(based on your clients and other considerations regarding your application).